# how to make a graph with standard error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwxUq.jpg)Hello, how do I make a trend bar

Hello, I have a series of data over time that I would like to plot in a way as similar as possible to the graph in the figure (with the standard error or deviation bars). Since my data are continuous I was wondering if there was a simple way in R to do it (putting the bars at definite intervals)?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Could you please share some code you have tried and reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Hello my data set first row looks like this :
Variants      ::     Posixtime      ::   E 
   N/A   ::     2020-11-02   ::   1.65
I have tried this 
'h<- ggplot(variants, aes(x=Posixtime, y=E)) +
  geom_point( ) +
  geom_smooth(se=FALSE)+
  #stat_summary(variants.data=mean_se, geom="ribbon"))'  but of course it only makes a ribbon, not what I wanted to have, I am very new to this though, sorry I do not know what is dput

Comment: Hi @Ask, could you please share your data using `dput(variants)` in your question above?

Comment: I am sorry I am not sure how that is supposed to work...

Comment: What you can do is run `dput(variants)` in your console and copy paste that output in your question above. So we can work with your reproducible data.

Comment: I see, but I have hundreds of thousands of data, and limited space in the commentary

Comment: Try: `dput(head(variants, 100))` to show the first 100 observations.

Comment: still too long. Will just put the dput(head(variants))

Comment: structure(list(Posixtime = structure(c(1604296800, 1604296800, 
1604296800, 1604296800, 1604296800, 1604296800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), E1N2 = c(1.65, 0.799999999999997, 1.47, 
0.890000000000001, 0.940000000000001, 2.55)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0):

You could use `geom_errorbar`, but you have data with only dates on the same day, that's why it looks weird. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
variants <- structure(list(Posixtime = structure(c(1604296800, 1604296800, 1604296800, 1604296800, 1604296800, 1604296800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), E1N2 = c(1.65, 0.799999999999997, 1.47, 0.890000000000001, 0.940000000000001, 2.55)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(variants, aes(x=Posixtime, y=E1N2)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = E1N2-0.1, ymax = E1N2 +0.1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>